# Is `using namespace foo;` useless?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a library that places all its declarations in namespace `foo`. I can then conveniently use the library by adding:

```
using namespace foo;
```

to my source files.  However, if any innocent name in `foo` (for example `class foo::socket`) is now ambiguous with global namespace names (for example `::socket()`).  What's more, there is no way to disambiguate them! Looks like `using namespace` is only useful for libraries that don't conflict with the global namespace, or am I missing something?

EDIT: by "disambiguate" I meant once for the scope, not at every use site, which is of course possible.

I guess we'll have to wait for modules for a satisfactory solution.

Comment: You can disambiguate by referencing the global namespace exactly as you showed in your question, ie, `::socket`

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I meant to disambiguate them for the rest of the scope, not at each usage (which is of course possible).

If I use `foo::socket` exclusively, I want to be able to write `using namespace foo; using foo::socket;` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

To answer your question - It is not useless, it does what you think.  And in some cases (like the one I have described below, it can be an acceptable thing to do)

It can indeed make names ambiguous, you have to be very careful when importing an entire namespace, see [Why is "using namespace std" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

I usually only import an entire namespace in the scope of something small like a function, for example

```
void func() {
    using namespace foo;
    // ...
}
```

Definitely never do it at the top of an implementation file.  Not until you are absolutely sure that it will not cause any conflicts.

Comment: Suppose I am sure that it will not cause conflict. The next day, the library changes, or my code changes, or I add a `#include`, and it breaks again.

Comment: Also, while importing in every function works, it causes endless repetition. Not very satisfying.

Comment: Until now, I never knew that we can import namespaces in the scope of a function. This was really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

> What's more, there is no way to disambiguate them!

You are very wrong on that account. Using the fully qualified name is always allowed:

```
int main() {
  using namespace foo;
  foo::socket fs;
  ::socket    s; // no ambiguity
}
```

What you are correct about is that it does indeed may cause ambiguity very easily. So the rule of thumb is not to pull in identifiers willy-nilly. And if you need to, do it at the smallest scope required. Moreover, try to pull just the things you need. i.e:

```
int main() {
  using foo::reader; // not using namespace foo; for a single identifier.
  reader r;
  socket s; // no ambiguity;
}
```

Of course, if you need many things from the namespace, it's better to pull everything into scope, IMO.

As a side note, sometimes pulling an identifier into scope with an identical one is a good thing. Consider a possible implementation for [`std::iter_swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iter_swap):

```
template<class ForwardIt1, class ForwardIt2>
void iter_swap(ForwardIt1 a, ForwardIt2 b)
{
   using std::swap;
   swap(*a, *b);
}
```

You may be wondering why bother with a using directive in this case, but the reason is actually better code. If the iterators point at a user defined class in namespace foo that defines a custom non-member swap function, then that function will be called after being found with [argument dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

If, on the other hand, no custom swap function is found, then `std::swap` will be called as a fallback. That's because the using directive makes it be a part of the candidate function set during overload resolution.